# Error message "function name is missing )." in visual foxpro 9.0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foxpro

I am having trouble converting a SQL statement to FoxPro. The trouble I'm having is that I get the error code " Function name is missing ). ", but I just can't figure out what or where the problem is. The trouble is in the line below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

`NVL(select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where tpaymentitem.invoiceid = 0 and tpaymentitem.programid = (select max(tinvoiceitem.programid) FROM tinvoiceitem),0) as prepay,;`

The whole foxpro code is below.

```
Select  acc.accountid,;
ti.invoiceid,;
ti.invoicedate,;
DATE() - ti.invoicedate as invage,;
sum(NVL([subtotalregular],0) + NVL([fedtaxregular],0) + NVL([statetaxregular],0) + NVL([localtaxregular],0)) as invamount, ;
NVL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid = ti.invoiceid),0) as paidamt,;
(sum(NVL([subtotalregular],0) + NVL([fedtaxregular],0) + NVL([statetaxregular],0) + NVL([localtaxregular],0)) - NVL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid = ti.invoiceid),0)) as invbalance,;
max(tii.programid) as programid,;
NVL(select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where tpaymentitem.invoiceid = 0 and tpaymentitem.programid = (select max(tinvoiceitem.programid) FROM tinvoiceitem),0) as prepay,;
do while com.stchargeinterest = 1 AND acc.nofincharge = 0 ;
  if DATE() - ti.invoicedate >= com.stmindaysforinterest ;
    ROUND((sum(NVL([subtotalregular],0) + NVL([fedtaxregular],0) + NVL([statetaxregular],0) + NVL([localtaxregular],0)) - NVL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid = ti.invoiceid),0)) * ((com.stinterestrate / 365) * DATE() - ti.invoicedate)),2);
  ENDif  ;
ENDdo as financecharge,;
com.stchargeinterest,;
com.stinterestrate,;
acc.nofincharge,;
com.stmindaysforinterest,;
com.stinterval;
INTO cursor tmpbalance;
FROM taccount acc;
INNER JOIN tcompany com ON com.companyid=acc.companyid;
LEFT JOIN tinvoice ti ON ti.accountid=acc.accountid;
LEFT JOIN tinvoiceitem tii ON ti.invoiceid=tii.invoiceid;
WHERE acc.accountid = m.cust_no AND acc.companyid = 1;
GROUP BY acc.accountid,ti.invoiceid,ti.invoicedate,com.stinterval,com.stchargeinterest ,;
com.stinterestrate,acc.nofincharge,com.stmindaysforinterest,acc.companyid
```

The SQL code I'm converting from is below and was originally captured from a stored procedure.

```
Select  acc.accountid,ti.invoiceid,ti.invoicedate,DateDiff(d,ti.invoicedate,getdate()) as invage,
sum(isnull([subtotalregular],0)+isnull([fedtaxregular],0)+isnull([statetaxregular],0)
    +isnull([localtaxregular],0)) as invamount, 
ISNULL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=ti.invoiceid),0) as paidamt,
(sum(isnull([subtotalregular],0)+isnull([fedtaxregular],0)+isnull([statetaxregular],0)
    +isnull([localtaxregular],0)) -
ISNULL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=ti.invoiceid),0)) as invbalance,
max(tii.programid) as programid,
ISNULL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid)),0) as prepay,
CASE WHEN (com.stchargeinterest = 1) AND (acc.nofincharge=0) THEN
    CASE WHEN DateDiff(d,ti.invoicedate,getdate()) >= com.stmindaysforinterest THEN
        ROUND((sum(isnull([subtotalregular],0)+isnull([fedtaxregular],0)+isnull([statetaxregular],0)+isnull([localtaxregular],0)) 
            -ISNULL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=ti.invoiceid),0)) 
            * ((com.stinterestrate / 365) * DateDiff(d,ti.invoicedate,getdate())),2)
    ELSE  0 END 
ELSE 0 END as financecharge,com.stchargeinterest ,com.stinterestrate,
acc.nofincharge,com.stmindaysforinterest,com.stinterval
INTO #tmpbalance
FROM taccount acc
INNER JOIN tcompany com ON com.companyid=acc.companyid
LEFT JOIN tinvoice ti ON ti.accountid=acc.accountid
LEFT JOIN tinvoiceitem tii ON ti.invoiceid=tii.invoiceid
WHERE acc.accountid= @accountid AND acc.companyid = @companyid
GROUP BY acc.accountid,ti.invoiceid,ti.invoicedate,com.stinterval,com.stchargeinterest ,
com.stinterestrate,acc.nofincharge,com.stmindaysforinterest,acc.companyid
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I don't know what I'm doing with `foxpro` or what the query is intended to do. However, check your parenthesis. The error message indicates that you are missing a closing parenthesis on the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate this:

```
ISNULL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid)),0) as prepay
```

as this:

```
NVL( (select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid)) ,0) as prepay
```

EDIT:

How about this:

```
( sum(NVL(amount,0)) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid) ) as prepay
```

Sorry, that won't work. It's a separate select statement from the main one.

EDIT 2:

```
(select sum(NVL(amount,0)) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid)) as prepay
```

Could try to simplify it, just to troubleshoot:

```
(select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where 1) as prepay
```

My apologies for stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Same error and when i try `SELECT sum(NVL(amount,0)) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid) as prepay,;` I get a new error of `command contains a unrecognized phrase\keyword` which is because of the `and` in the `where` clause

Comment: I was thinking you don't need the `SELECT`. You already have one at the start of the query. You're saying that without it you get the same original error?

Comment: Correct, I get the same original error of `Function name is missing ).` when I run `( sum(NVL(amount,0)) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid) ) as prepay` I even went as far as to count the bumber of open and closed paren's to see if the count is off and it isn't.

Comment: Is it the correct syntax for `foxpro` to have a semicolon at the end of each line? I'm not seeing that in code examples posted elsewhere.

Comment: Yes it acts in the opposite way that it does in SQL, so it tells FoxPro that the next line is a continuation of the previous line; and not a termination like in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the stabs in the dark. I think I found the issue with the `MAX()` function in FoxPro. It looks like there need to be to 2 expressions instead of one like SQL. So these seems too work `NVL((select sum(amount) from tpaymentitem where invoiceid=0 and programid = max(tii.programid,0)),0) as prepay,;` Gotta love FoxPro.

Comment: Oh duh. That makes sense. Nice job!

Comment: The issue is that FoxPro had a MAX() function that let you find the maximum among a list of (up to 26) values long before it had SQL commands. So, MAX(a,b) uses the old FoxPro function. I don't think you're going to get what you want with the syntax you show. Try changing the = to IN before the condition involving MAX() and see if it works.

Comment: It still errors out with the `in` condition. It still wants to use the old foxpro `MAX()` command. Your correct that it will properly not get me the results I want, but right now I'm just trying to get it to compile without any errors.